# Visual studio code flutter extensions

Tags: flutter, dart, visual-studio-code

I’m new to flutter. Are there any extensions that can improve my code writing speed? For example a way to create a widget automatically and not manually.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can install `"Awesome Flutter Snippet"` Extension, it's pretty famous and useful, it will help you wrap any widget on top of any widget.

You can also explore other Extension by searching in extension on the VSCode

[image: VSCode Extension]

Answer (score 0):

- Pubspec Assist
- Error Lens
- Awesome Flutter Snippets

Answer (score 0):

I use

- Dart
- Flutter
- Awesome Flutter Snippets
- Error Lens
- Material Icon Theme
- Dart Barrel File Generator
- [dart-data-class-generator](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=dotup.dart-data-class-generator)
- bloc (sate-management)
- Flutter Riverpod Snippets(state-management)
- TODO Highlight/Todo Tree
- Code Runner
- Android (for android console log)
- …

---

My extension list (some aren't needed for flutter, above list is enough)

**Author => extension name**

- aaron-bond => better-comments
- adelphes => android-dev-ext
- alefragnani => Bookmarks
- austin => code-gnu-global
- BendixMa => dart-data-class-generator
- blaxou => freezed
- byi8220 => indented-block-highlighting
- christian-kohler => npm-intellisense
- cschlosser => doxdocgen
- danielpinto8zz6 => c-cpp-compile-run
- Dart-Code => dart-code
- Dart-Code => flutter
- DavidAnson => vscode-markdownlint
- dotup => dart-data-class-generator
- eamodio => gitlens
- ecmel => vscode-html-css
- eg2 => vscode-npm-script
- esbenp => prettier-vscode
- FelixAngelov => bloc
- formulahendry => code-runner
- GrapeCity => gc-excelviewer
- Gruntfuggly => todo-tree
- hediet => vscode-drawio
- jeff-hykin => better-cpp-syntax
- jock => svg
- josetr => cmake-language-support-vscode
- luanpotter => dart-import
- mikestead => dotenv
- miquelddg => dart-barrel-file-generator
- mkxml => vscode-filesize
- ms-dotnettools => vscode-dotnet-runtime
- ms-python => python
- ms-vscode-remote => remote-containers
- ms-vscode-remote => remote-ssh
- ms-vscode-remote => remote-ssh-edit
- ms-vscode-remote => remote-wsl
- ms-vscode => cmake-tools
- ms-vscode => cpptools
- ms-vscode => cpptools-extension-pack
- ms-vscode => cpptools-themes
- Nash => awesome-flutter-snippets
- PKief => material-icon-theme
- ritwickdey => LiveServer
- robert-brunhage => flutter-riverpod-snippets
- shd101wyy => markdown-preview-enhanced
- streetsidesoftware => code-spell-checker
- tomoki1207 => pdf
- twxs => cmake
- usernamehw => errorlens
- WakaTime => vscode-wakatime
- wayou => vscode-todo-highlight
- wix => vscode-import-cost
- yzhang => markdown-all-in-one
- zrachod => mono-snippets